# Calculating an average while ignoring certain values

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a set of numbers e.g. [10,45,3,0,0,0,27] and I want to average every number that isn't a 0. So in this case it would be (10 + 45 + 3 + 27) / 4. How can I do this in excel, given that I will change the 0's to non-0's at some point, so the average will need to be updated?

Comment: In a formula? VBA? If the latter you would just loop them; how depends on what your set actually *is* ...

Comment: In a formula preferably. I'm a beginner with excel. My data is just a score achieved from 8 assignments. So I will add the score each time I receive one.

Answer (score 4):

```
=AVERAGEIF(Range,"<>"&0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Excel's `=COUNTIF(Range, Criteria)` function, e.g. in your case `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,**">0"**)` to count every value greater than 0 and then divide by the number.

Also this might help: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/